# Multiple layout files Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two XML files for my layout - main.xml and test.xml.  Here is the code in test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:id="@+id/menu_objoptions"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:padding="10dp"  >  
    </ListView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to get an instance of the ListView with

> findViewById( R.id.menu_objoptions )

it returns null. Why is that?

EDIT: here is the relevant java code:

```
public void objClick(String objid, long X, long Y) {

        final String objID = objid;
        final long x = X;
        final long y = Y;

        try {
            mHandle.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    PopupWindow popUp;
                    LinearLayout layout;

                    ListView mainListView;  
                    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;  
                    String[] planets = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
                            "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    

                    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();  
                    planetList.addAll( Arrays.asList(planets) );  

                    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mHandle, R.layout.menu_objoptions_row, planetList);  

                    listAdapter.add( "Ceres" );  
                    listAdapter.add( "Pluto" );  
                    listAdapter.add( "Haumea" );  
                    listAdapter.add( "Makemake" );  
                    listAdapter.add( "Eris" );  

                    popUp   = new PopupWindow(mHandle);
                    layout  = new LinearLayout(mHandle);

                    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    mainListView = (ListView) mHandle.findViewById( R.id.menu_objoptions );  
                    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );     
                    layout.addView(mainListView);

                    popUp.setContentView(layout);
                    popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                    popUp.showAtLocation(rlmain, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 10, 10);
                    popUp.update((int)x,(int)y, 300, 80);

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
```

NullPointerException is thrown at this line:

```
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

Comment: what is mHandle ? is this a view ? where the mHandle first initialized?

Comment: mHandle is my main Activity, context.

Comment: where are u implementing this code ? in an activity or in a fragment ?

Comment: in my main activity. In onCreate() method I initialize a class that I've created and pass the handle of main avtivity like this:  SomeObj obj = new SomeObj(MainActivity.this).  And that's what mHandle is in that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it returns null. Why is that?

Probably you calling it too early. You need to call it after

```
setContentView(R.layout.someLayout);
```

is called. `setContentView` method should be called before you start initialising another widgets, immediately after you call parent's constructor.

### Update:

So in your case you need set your `LinearLayout` as **contentView** before you want to initialise any widget in your case `ListView`.

My suggestion is to initialise your `LinearLayout` in `onCreate()` method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourLinearLayout); // this must be called first
   ListView list = findViewById(R.id.menu_objoptions); // now it should works.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting ContentView first, but it outputs IllegalStateException on this line:  layout.addView(mainListView);

Comment: You don't need to call `addView`method, your `ListView` is already in layout(look at XML). all what you need is to initialise `ListView` with `findViewById(R.id.listId)` and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the LinearLayout after set the contentViewById (.....) in Oncreate() method.

The Code should be

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
               setContentView(R.layout.test);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.menu_objoptions);
```

Make sure that you are using  **LinearLayout** reference for initialization.

Comment: but menu_objoptions is a ListView not LinearLayout. Why should I cast it? It outputs error: exception ClassCastException on that exact line where I'm initialising LinearLayout according to your code